# Debugging Azure Functions with Visual Studio: Break Points don't work

Tags: c#, azure, debugging, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I have a C# Azure Function that I develop in Visual Studio 2017. Everything works fine but when I want to debug locally and set a break point, the break point is not hit and the following message is displayed: `'The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.'`

How can I get the break points working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to use break points do the following: in Visual Studio go to Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General

There uncheck `Use Managed Compatibility Mode`.

Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You may have already verified this, but make sure you are building in debug mode. This can be verified by the project properties under the build tab. If it is already in debug mode, right click the Solution in solution explorer, click "clean solution" and rebuild. The last thing I would verify is that "Just My Code" option is disabled in in the Debug/General settings.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether your solution is in Debug mode.
2. Go to Debug -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols -> click load all symbols and
   choose Load all modules,unless excluded option in Automatic symbol loading preference.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too simple for an answer but restarting Visual Studio worked for me.